# Web scraping using python goes all wrong

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a novice in web scraping in python. I studied [this](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/amazon-web-scraping-using-beautifulsoup#comments) article to know more about web scraping and tried to implement my first project in web scraping. However, I got stuck on the first portion of the code block.

Code

```
no_pages = 2

def get_data(pageNo):  
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
    r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Womens-Fashion-Sneakers/zgbs/fashion/679394011'+str(pageNo)+'?ie=UTF8&pg='+str(pageNo), headers=headers)#, proxies=proxies)
    content = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    #print(soup)

    alls = []
    for d in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'a-section a-spacing-none aok-relative'}):
        #print(d)
        name = d.find('span', attrs={'class':'zg-text-center-align'})
        n = name.find_all('img', alt=True)
        #print(n[0]['alt'])
        #author = d.find('a', attrs={'class':'a-size-small a-link-child'})
        rating = d.find('span', attrs={'class':'a-link-normal'})
        users_rated = d.find('a', attrs={'class':'a-size-small a-link-normal'})
        price = d.find('span', attrs={'class':'p13n-sc-price'})

        all1=[]

        if name is not None:
            #print(n[0]['alt'])
            all1.append(n[0]['alt'])
        else:
            all1.append("unknown-product")
        '''
        if author is not None:
            #print(author.text)
            all1.append(author.text)
        elif author is None:
            author = d.find('span', attrs={'class':'a-size-small a-color-base'})
            if author is not None:
                all1.append(author.text)
            else:    
                all1.append('0')
          '''

        if rating is not None:
            #print(rating.text)
            all1.append(rating.text)
        else:
            all1.append('-1')

        if users_rated is not None:
            #print(price.text)
            all1.append(users_rated.text)
        else:
            all1.append('0')     

        if price is not None:
            #print(price.text)
            all1.append(price.text)
        else:
            all1.append('0')
        alls.append(all1)    
    return alls
```

I comment out

```
'''
            if author is not None:
                #print(author.text)
                all1.append(author.text)
            elif author is None:
                author = d.find('span', attrs={'class':'a-size-small a-color-base'})
                if author is not None:
                    all1.append(author.text)
                else:    
                    all1.append('0')
              '''
```

because I did not use the popular book as mentioned in the article. Instead of bestseller books, I used bestseller sneakers in my program.

Next portion:

```
results = []
for i in range(1, no_pages+1):
    results.append(get_data(i))
flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
df = pd.DataFrame(flatten(results),columns=['Book Name','Author','Rating','Customers_Rated', 'Price'])
df.to_csv('amazon_products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

The file('amazon_products.csv') that has been generated using the code was an empty file. I tried to print out the results array as well. I found that result was an empty array. The for loop iterated two times. I cannot understand the functionality of the for a loop as well.

How can I overcome the difficulty?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You haven't done much checking here.  Did you print out your exact URL and try to fetch it in your browser?  If you had, you'd see that you're adding the page number twice, and the first one is in the wrong spot.   It changes the page identifier (679394011) to a number that isn't found (6793940111).

Comment: your url is incorrect. You are missing the substring `'ref=zg_bs_pg_'`. Try: `'https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Womens-Fashion-Sneakers/zgbs/fashion/679394011/ref=zg_bs_pg_'+str(pageNo)+'?ie=UTF8&pg='+str(pageNo)`

Comment: @chitown88 Can you please let me know from where you get the `ref=zg_bs_pg`? I got `https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Womens-Fashion-Sneakers/zgbs/fashion/679394011` url from the address bar of my browser. Additionally if I copy this url and paste it again in the address bar it works fine.

Comment: Ok I got the substring. I got it from the page number section. If I right click on page and select inspect  it will open the ahref where I can get the substring. Am I right?

Comment: Yes there. Or simply, I saw it on the address url. It’s also in the example from that tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the correct url. If you go to the that url `'https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Womens-Fashion-Sneakers/zgbs/fashion/6793940111?ie=UTF8&pg=1`' that you are feeding in, you'll see their "Sorry can't find that page" message.

I also made a few modifications to the code. I'm not a fan of creating a list of lists. The create a list of lists, and then append that to another list. I don't know why they would do that. It then needs an extra line of code to flatten out a nested list of list of lists, which they do at

```
flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
df = pd.DataFrame(flatten(results),columns=['Book Name','Author','Rating','Customers_Rated', 'Price'])
```

The better way to avoid needing that to flatten out is just keep it flat initially and concatenate them together. So it would be better to change

```
results = []
for i in range(1, no_pages+1):
    results.append(get_data(i))
```

to

```
results = []
for i in range(1, no_pages+1):
    results += get_data(i)
```

I have no idea why they did that in the tutorial, as to me it's unnecessary and makes it more confusing when learning.

So that block of code is better as:

```
results = []
for i in range(1, no_pages+1):
    results += get_data(i)
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Book Name','Author','Rating','Customers_Rated', 'Price']) 
df.to_csv('amazon_products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

There's still and issue here with your code as you don't have 5 columns in your list (no Author), but rather 4 columns/items in your lists. So you'll get an error there.

Because of that, my method would be to create a list of dictionaries, so that you handle the columns more dynamically. The column names are the keys and you have a value of that. Then you only need to feed in the list of dictionaries into pandas and not worry about if the number of elements in the list, matches the length of the column names you have in that list.

Since you are learning, some of this may be confusing, but I think is a better way to handle it.

So here's my modified code:

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

no_pages = 2
def get_data(pageNo):  
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
    url = 'https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Womens-Fashion-Sneakers/zgbs/fashion/679394011/ref=zg_bs_pg_'+str(pageNo)+'?ie=UTF8&pg='+str(pageNo)
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)#, proxies=proxies)
    content = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    #print(soup)

    rows = []
    for d in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'a-section a-spacing-none aok-relative'}):
        #print(d)
        name = d.find('span', attrs={'class':'zg-text-center-align'})
        n = name.find_all('img', alt=True)
        rating = d.find('span', attrs={'class':'a-icon-alt'}) #<--- it's under <span> with class a-icon-alt, not a-link-normal
        users_rated = d.find('a', attrs={'class':'a-size-small a-link-normal'})
        price = d.find('span', attrs={'class':'p13n-sc-price'})

        row={}

        if name is not None:
            #print(n[0]['alt'])
            row['Name'] = n[0]['alt']
        else:
            row['Name'] = "unknown-product"

        if rating is not None:
            #print(rating.text)
            row['Rating'] = rating.text
        else:
            row['Rating'] = 'N/A'

        if users_rated is not None:
            #print(price.text)
            row['Customers_Rated'] = users_rated.text
        else:
            row['Customers_Rated'] = '0'   

        if price is not None:
            #print(price.text)
            row['Price'] = price.text
        else:
            row['Price'] = '0'
        rows.append(row)    
    return rows



results = []
for i in range(1, no_pages+1):
    results += get_data(i)
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
df.to_csv('amazon_products.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.head(10).to_string())
                                                                                                                      Name              Rating Customers_Rated   Price
0                                        UMYOGO Women's Running Shoes Non Slip Athletic Tennis Walking Blade Type Sneakers  4.3 out of 5 stars          17,300  $39.99
1  Women's Walking Shoes Sock Sneakers - Mesh Slip On Air Cushion Lady Girls Modern Jazz Dance Easy Shoes Platform Loafers  4.0 out of 5 stars          70,000  $23.03
2                                                                               adidas Women's Cloudfoam Pure Running Shoe  4.7 out of 5 stars          43,001  $18.69
3                             STQ Slip On Breathe Mesh Walking Shoes Women Fashion Sneakers Comfort Wedge Platform Loafers  4.1 out of 5 stars          31,791  $29.84
4                                          ZGR Women’s Canvas Low Top Sneaker Lace-up Classic Casual Shoes Black and White  4.4 out of 5 stars          11,230  $16.99
5                                                                     Skechers Women's D'Lites Memory Foam Lace-up Sneaker  4.5 out of 5 stars          33,781  $39.99
6                                                                                       adidas Women's Grand Court Sneaker  4.7 out of 5 stars          17,941  $30.44
7                                    Wonesion Womens Walking Running Shoes Athletic Blade Non Slip Tennis Fashion Sneakers  4.4 out of 5 stars           4,543  $29.99
8                             Deevike Running Shoes Women Walking Tennis Non Slip Air Cushion Comfortable Fashion Sneakers  4.4 out of 5 stars              41  $39.99
9                                                                                     Blowfish Malibu Women's Play Sneaker  4.7 out of 5 stars          11,805  $22.90
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have some doubts here. As you mentioned *There's still and issue here with your code as you don't have 5 columns in your list (no Author), but rather 4 columns/items in your lists* What if I change the statement as `df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Shoe Name'','Rating','Customers_Rated', 'Price']) `. Can you please explain `for i in range(1, no_pages+1):
    results += get_data(i)` this?

Comment: And to answer that first question. Yes that’ll work, provided you keep your code as it was have (with the list of lists), as opposed to what I did with the dictionary. So again, shoot me an email, I’ll show you the code for both ways and you can sort of see how each work. Both ways are fine I think, it’s just sort of a preference at the end of the day.